# Client/Server communication WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp

I found this very useful program that was written for a Console application:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

I ran it and it works but what I want is to do the equivalent with WPF.

Could somebody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new WPF Application, copy the `serv` class in a new file and include it in your project, write the other stuff in your MainWindow constructor.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sorry but I'm not a programmer and therefore I had some trouble when rtying to use the code in WPF... I got it to work now.